# What is the right way in flutter to make http post requests with image data?

Tags: flutter, post, file-upload, multipartform-data, socketexception

I'm feeling stuck with flutter while trying to upload an image to the server. I'm receiving io/network exceptions.

I have tried sending the image data as `MultipartFile` in the request files or as encoded JSON in the request body. Check code and error trace below.

Note, `imageBytes` is of type `Uint8List` and `Warehouse.post` is just calling `http.post` and is working just fine across the rest of the app.

Any suggestions or guidance would be of tremendous help.

The multipart approach below throws `SocketException`. (trace below)

```
final request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', Uri.parse(Warehouse.baseUrl + '/sudoku/detect-box/'));
request.files.add(http.MultipartFile.fromBytes('image', imageBytes));
request.headers.addAll({'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'});
print('request: ${request.toString()}, ${request.files.map((f) => 'Field: ${f.field}, ${f.contentType}').join(', ')}');
// send the request
http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();
print('[Box Detection] response: ${response.statusCode}');
response.stream.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((value) {
  print('[ResponseStream] $value');
});
```

Error Trace:

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: SocketException: Write failed (OS Error: Broken pipe, errno = 32), address = api.staging.captain.lavee-singh.com, port = 61929
#0      _NativeSocket.write (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1119:34)
#1      _RawSocket.write (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1765:15)
#2      _ExternalBuffer.readToSocket (dart:io/secure_socket.dart:1203:26)
#3      _RawSecureSocket._writeSocket (dart:io/secure_socket.dart:966:16)
#4      _RawSecureSocket._writeHandler (dart:io/secure_socket.dart:743:5)
#5      _RawSecureSocket._eventDispatcher (dart:io/secure_socket.dart:728:9)
#6      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1444:13)
#7      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1335:19)
#8      _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1244:7)
#9      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:341:11)
#10     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:271:7)

#11     _SyncStreamControllerDispatch._sendData (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:733:19)
#12     _StreamController._add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:607:7)
#13     _StreamController.add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:554:5)
#14     new _RawSocket.<anonymous closure> (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1707:23)
#15     _NativeSocket.issueWriteEvent.issue (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1239:14)
#16     _NativeSocket.issueWriteEvent (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1246:7)
#17     _NativeSocket.multiplex (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1267:11)
#18     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:187:12)
```

The second approach, with JSON encoded request body:

```
final response = await Warehouse.post(
  '/sudoku/detect-box/',
  body: json.encode({'image': base64.encode(imageBytes)}),
);
print('[Box Detection] response: $response');
```

Error Trace:

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: 
#0      IOClient.send (package:http/src/io_client.dart:66:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      BaseClient._sendUnstreamed (package:http/src/base_client.dart:93:32)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      _withClient (package:http/http.dart:164:12)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      Warehouse.post (package:sudoku_plus/sudoku/api.dart:89:20)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      SudokuAPI.boxDetection (package:sudoku_plus/sudoku/api.dart:223:22)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

Comment: You maybe want to try DIO for me the more awesome packages to http manage, https://pub.dev/packages/dio

Comment: This looks like something amazing, thanks, will try!